# Trying to remove Blynk server from Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: port-forwarding

Having purged the installation files for Blynk local server on my Raspberry Pi, there seems to be a relic left & I despite hours spent searching, I can't find how to get rid it, so any help would be gratefully received.
The issue is some form of port forwarding; if I browse to the pi's IP, port 8080, the browser is redirected to a blynk webpage (https://www.blynk.cc/), which is unreachable, but that's not the issue.
Question is: what do I need to do to eliminate this redirect.
Help!

Comment: `sudo netstat -pant | grep :8080` will tell you what is listening on port 8080 - if you don't understand what you see in the output (assuming there is any output), post the output of the command in your question

Comment: how did you install and remove the program?

Comment: Thanks for responding,
1. There's no response to sudo netstat -pant | grep :8080
2. There were several steps to removing the program: sudo apt-get remove --purge oracle-java8-jdk openjdk-7-jre oracle-java7-jdk openjdk-8-jre, sudo apt-get autoremove, sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get purge node nodejs node.js -y, and finally sudo apt-get purge blynk-library -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package blynk-library

Comment: Inspired by no response to "sudo netstat -pant | grep :8080", I wondered if the problem lay elsewhere. I found that a different browser did not suffer the "redirect". So, I did a complete uninstall of Firefox & re-installed a clean copy. Problem solved, although weird, it seems that somehow, use of the Blink server on the pi had "corrupted" Firefox. Makes no sense to me, but anyway all is now OK. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `There's no response to sudo netstat -pant | grep :8080` - in that case, the pi isn't even responsible for your problem

Comment: Please don't explain additional information in comments. Instead [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/108822/edit) the question and put it there.